# Resin 3.0.18 / IIS6 Server is down message "Server is currently unavailable or down for maintenance"

Tags: iis-6, resin

Is there any way to change this error message? It appears when Resin is not running so I would think it is an IIS6 error message but the source code of the page shows this text commented out:

- Unfortunately, Microsoft has added a clever new
- "feature" to Internet Explorer.  If the text in
- an error's message is "too small", specifically
- less than 512 bytes, Internet Explorer returns
- its own error message.  Yes, you can turn that
- off, but *surprise* it's pretty tricky to find
- buried as a switch called "smart error
- messages"  That means, of course, that many of
- Resin's error messages are censored by default.
- And, of course, you'll be shocked to learn that
- IIS always returns error messages that are long
- enough to make Internet Explorer happy.  The
- workaround is pretty simple: pad the error
- message with a big comment to push it over the
- five hundred and twelve byte minimum.  Of course,
- that's exactly what you're reading right now.

I've found nothing in the documentation for either IIS6 or for Resin for this error message.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, Resin and some other Web Servers add an HTML comment to the error page to pad the message such that the true error is presented.

e.g. http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2004/06/22/lame-internet-explorer-script-error-message/

Sample comment as seen on the web:

```
<!–-
  Unfortunately, Microsoft has added a clever new
  “feature” to Internet Explorer. If the text in
  an error’s message is “too small”, specifically
  less than 512 bytes, Internet Explorer returns
  its own error message. Yes, you can turn that
  off, but *surprise* it’s pretty tricky to find
  buried as a switch called “smart error
  messages” That means, of course, that many of
  Resin’s error messages are censored by default.
  And, of course, you’ll be shocked to learn that
  IIS always returns error messages that are long
  enough to make Internet Explorer happy. The
  workaround is pretty simple: pad the error
  message with a big comment to push it over the
  five hundred and twelve byte minimum. Of course,
  that’s exactly what you’re reading right now.
-->
```

I should note that this message **should** be a comment on the page (e.g. not visible) if it is visible, something has gone wrong. e.g. maybe the file is being served up as text, not text/html?

Comment: I might have worded this badly. I'm just referencing the comment to show that it's a Resin issue even though Resin isn't up. My question is where can I modify this specific error so I can change the page layout? Thanks!